# Scrapy: Crawled but not scraped

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

with the suggestions provided and with lot of trail, i was able to get the crawl work for single page. Now, I have tried to make changes to code, to implement multiple rules, but the results doesn't look good. Here is the brief description of what i'm trying to do,

For the start_url=ttp://sfbay.craigslist.org/ - I use parse_items_1 to identify http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo and parse the same to identify the link

In level 2, for the links in ttp://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo , I need to use parse_items_2 to identify the links like http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/index100.html and parse the same.

The spider is able to Crawl (I can see the displays), but the links are not getting scrapped.

```
2013-02-13 11:23:55+0530 [craigs] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/index100.html> (referer: http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/)
('**parse_items_2:', [u'Development Associate'], [u'http://sfbay.craigslist.org/eby/npo/3610841951.html'])
('**parse_items_2:', [u'Resource Development Assistant'], [u'http://sfbay.craigslist.org/eby/npo/3610835088.html'])
```

but the link and title, when scrapped is null.

```
2013-02-13 11:23:55+0530 [craigs] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/index100.html>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2013-02-13 11:23:55+0530 [craigs] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/index100.html>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
```

Code details:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from myspider.items import CraigslistSampleItem


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["sfbay.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html")), callback="parse_items_2", follow= True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'sfbay.craigslist.org/npo')), callback="parse_items_1", follow= True),
        )

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.items = []
        self.item = CraigslistSampleItem()

    def parse_items_1(self, response):
#       print response.url
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//div")
        for title in titles:
            self.item ["title"] = title.select("//li/a/text()").extract()
            self.item ["link"] = title.select("//li/a/@href").extract()
            print ('**parse-items_1:', self.item["title"])
            self.items.append(self.item)
        return self.items

    def parse_items_2(self, response):
#       print response.url
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        for title in titles:
            self.item ["title"] = title.select("a/text()").extract()
            self.item ["link"] = title.select("a/@href").extract()
            print ('**parse_items_2:', self.item["title"], self.item["link"])
            self.items.append(self.item)
        return self.items
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Since the answers payala and I gave helped to resolve the initial issue of pages not being crawled, please pick the best answer and accept it (and also remember to upvote those answers when your rep is high enough).

Comment: Sure. I will. Do you know whats wrong with the current code. I mean, It crawled and when I print the Item list, I can see the exact titile and links, but the info is not getting scrapped.

Comment: Yes, and I have fixed it. Please accept one of the answers to your previous question and I will post my fix as an answer here.

Comment: I did and would have done it anyway. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the scrapy tutorial, items are created within a callback and then returned to be passed further down the line rather than being tied to an instance of the spider class. Thus removing the init section and rewriting some of the callback code appears to fix the issue.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from tutorial.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["sfbay.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html")), callback="parse_items_2", follow= True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'sfbay.craigslist.org/npo')), callback="parse_items_1", follow= True),
        )

    def parse_items_1(self, response):
        items = []
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//div")
        for title in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = title.select("//li/a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = title.select("//li/a/@href").extract()
            print ('**parse-items_1:', item["title"])
            items.append(item)
        return items

    def parse_items_2(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = title.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = title.select("a/@href").extract()
            print ('**parse_items_2:', item["title"], item["link"])
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

To test, I dumped the crawled items to a file (`scrapy crawl craigs -t json -o items.json`). I noted that there were null entries every so often and a lot of "Terms of Use" links. These suggest that your extract xpaths could be tightened up, but other than that it appears to be working.

Comment: That worked very well. Thank you. Defining the Item = [], will this not initialize the item list. What if the same list need to be used to capture the contents from 2 different parses.